# Simple average question, if I have 2 rolls at 1/100 and 1/250 respectively, what is the odds to get at least 1?

Tags: probability, statistics

I get 2 rolls every time.

So let's say I have a 1/100 chance to get a blue balloon and 1/250 chance to get a gold balloon. They are rolled separately.

First roll is the 1/100 to get the blue balloon and 2nd roll is 1/250 to get gold balloon.

How do I calculate the average chance to get either a gold or blue balloon for each 2 rolls ? (There is a chance you can get both blue and gold)

What I assumed is we just do 1/100 + 1/250 but i don't think thats correct

P(at least one per two rolls) = 1/100 + 1/250 = 1/71.4

Comment: It's not quite correct because it overlooks the possibility that you get both.  What is the probability that you get neither?  Subtract that probability from $1$ and you have the probability that you get at least one.

Comment: 1 - (probability of no blue balloon times probability of no gold ballon).

Comment: 1 - (99/100 * 249/250) = 1/71.6 ?

Comment: So do you also want to include the probability of getting both or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it easier to understand, let's consider all cases individually.
If you get a blue balloon on the first try and nothing on the second, the probability of that happening is $\frac{1}{100}\cdot\frac{249}{250}=\frac{249}{25000}$. Similarly, the chance of doing the opposite (no balloon on the first try and gold balloon on the second is $\frac{99}{100}\cdot\frac{1}{250}=\frac{99}{25000}$. The probability of getting both balloons is $\frac{1}{100}\cdot\frac{1}{250}=\frac{1}{25000}$. Adding all these probabilities up gives $\frac{249}{25000}+\frac{99}{25000}+\frac{1}{25000}=\frac{349}{25000}$. So that is the probability of getting at least one balloon.

In order to double check this answer, we just have to find the probability for you to get neither balloon, which is $\frac{99}{100}\cdot\frac{249}{250}=\frac{24651}{25000}$. The answer should be $1-$ the above value, which is $1-\frac{24651}{25000}=\frac{349}{25000}$.

(P. S. If you are looking for only one balloon and not two, just sum the first two probabilities to get $\frac{249}{25000}+\frac{99}{25000}=\frac{348}{25000}$.)